# how to extract text from mupdf latest version 1.14

Tags: android, mupdf

im integrating mupdf latest version i.e 1.14, in this libs files and jni calling methods are changed.i tried with StructuredText like

```
StructuredText.TextBlock[] blocks = (core.page).toStructuredText().getBlocks();
    if(blocks==null)
        return;
       for(int i=0; i<blocks.length;i++){
           StructuredText.TextBlock block = blocks[i];

           if(block==null)continue;
           for(int j=0;j<block.lines.length;j++){

               StructuredText.TextLine lines = block.lines[j];


               for(StructuredText.TextChar ch:lines.chars ){
                   if(!ch.isWhitespace()){
                       Log.e("Chars",Character.toString((char)ch.c)/*+ch.quad.toString()+*/+"");
                   }else {
                       Log.e("Chars",Character.toString((char)ch.c)/*+ch.quad.toString()+*/+"space"+ch.c);
                   }

               }
           }
```

but text is not getting
 please suggest me that how extract text from latest version in android